# How to show $A \backslash (A \cap B \cap C) = A \backslash (B \cap C)$?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, discrete-mathematics, elementary-set-theory

In a proof the following two lines appear:

$$[A \backslash (A \cap B \cap C)] \cup [B \backslash (A \cap B \cap C)] \cup [C \backslash (A \cap B \cap C)]$$
$$= [A \backslash (B \cap C)] \cup [B \backslash (A \cap C)] \cup [C \backslash (A \cap B)]$$

From sketching some venn diagrams, I do not see how the second line follows from the first. Could someone shed some light on this for me please?

Comment: It all comes down to how we define the subtraction of sets, as shown in MathFail's answer

Answer (score 3):

$$\begin{align}A\backslash(A\cap B\cap C)&=A\cap (A\cap B\cap C)^c\\
\\
&=A\cap(A^c\cup(B\cap C)^c)\\
\\
&=(A\cap A^c)\cup(A\cap (B\cap C)^c)\\
\\
&=\emptyset\cup (A\backslash(B\cap C))\\
\\
&=A\backslash(B\cap C)
\end{align}$$

Answer (score 0):

It follows from the more general fact that $A-(A \cap E)=A-E$. This is very easy to see using a Venn diagram. Then you have that $A-(A \cap B \cap C)=A-(A \cap (B \cap C))=A-(B \cap C)$.